# Jest to mock Stripe

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I want to test my nodejs code using Jest.
In my code I use stripe.

When requiring stripe you have to use this line

```
const stripe=require('stripe')("apikey");
```

in order to be able to access the stripe methods.

Obviously that's the library I want to mock, but if I do

```
jest.mock('stripe');
```

I cannot mock the stripe methods I need as it's like doing a require without passing the key in the higher order function.

I could not find any correlation around.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I figure you'll need to build your entire Stripe SDK mock. This is what's working for me atm:

```
// Stripe SDK mock
jest.mock('stripe', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            skus: {
                retrieve: (sku, callback) => {
                    callback({}, {});
                }
            }
        };
    });
});
```

The above mock will return empty `sku` object when calling `stripe.skus.retrieve(req.query.sku, function(err, sku) { ... })`

Same should go for the rest. If you want this mock to return different kinds of data depending on input, you'll need to implement that logic in the mock.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I've found a solution by just assign stirpe.element.function=jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(value))