# Mock stripe apis using jest in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, stripe-payments

I want to mock stripe apis but unable to figure out how to do it. I'm creating the session using below code-

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('key');
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: 'usd',
              product_data: {
                name: 'abs',
                images: ['url'],
              },
              unit_amount: 100,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?back=true&order_id=${req.clientReferenceId}`,
        metadata: req.metadata,
        client_reference_id: req.clientReferenceId,
        customer_email: req.customerEmail,
        billing_address_collection: 'required',
      });
```

I cannot import stripe in test file as it will require API key. How to do this?
PS- I tried by following this - [Jest to mock Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492219/jest-to-mock-stripe) but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stripe` exported as a function, when you want to mock it you can use `jest.doMock` helper.

Imagine that you have an index.js like this:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('key'); // You use require('stripe') as a function

exports.CreateSession = async (req) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    // information to create session
  });
  return session;
}
```

Then, testing file will be like this:

```
describe('Create session', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules(); // importance line
  });

  it('creates the session', async () => {
    const req = {
      unitAmount: 100,
      imageUrl: '',
      metadata: {
        userId: '1'
      }
    };

    jest.doMock('stripe', () => {
      // instead of mocking return an object, let’s return a function
      return jest.fn(() => ({ // when the function be called, it return an object like this
        checkout: {
          sessions: {
            create: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
              sessionId: '123' // sessionId instead of id , right?
            })),
          },
        },
      }));
    });

    const { CreateSession } = require('./index'); // import function what you need to test
    const resp = await CreateSession(req); // execute with a parameter
    expect(resp.sessionId).toBe('123');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Just one change, Instead of sessionId it will be Id

Comment: Holy bleep this worked like a charm. Thanks @hoangdv

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `stripe` mock before use it:

```
jest.mock("stripe", ()=> ({
  checkout: {
    sessions: {
      create: jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve()) //--> resolve data you are expecting
    }
  }
}));
```

Also you can use the [Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)

`__mocks__/stripe.js`

```
const stripe = {
      checkout: {
        sessions: {
          create: jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve()) //--> resolve data you are expecting
        }
      }
    };

export default stripe;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But It is still not getting mocked- describe('Create session', () => {
    it('creates the session', async () => {
      const req = {unitAmount: 100, imageUrl: '', metadata: new Metadata({userId: '1'})};
      jest.mock('stripe', () => ({
        checkout: {
          sessions: {
            create: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({id: '123'})),
          },
        },
      }));
      const resp = await mock.createSession(new CreateSessionRequest(req));
      expect(resp.sessionId).toBe('123');
    });
  });

Comment: How is mock.createSession and CreateSessionRequest implemented?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by that